# How do I run Python code line-by-line in Atom using Script?

Tags: python, atom-editor

In Atom, I am currently using Script to execute code. However, after I run the full code, if I try to execute one line it's as if all information disappears from cache.

For instance, if I run the entire below script it will work and print 5. But if I run the whole script, then try to run only line 2, it will throw an error saying x is undefined.

```
1. x = 5

2. print(x)
```

Anyone know how to solve? I'd rather not be running the entire script every time since my actual files are quite large.

Thank you!!

Comment: you can highlight the line (or code block) that you want to run and press `cmd+i` or `shift+ctrl+b` if on windows. There is also [this](https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-debugger-python) debugger

Comment: I tried this! But it throws the following error when I try to ruin the print:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/_5/_1qb8n9x37q_bxczh99m2_l80000gp/T/atom_script_tempfiles/ed045cb0-d1c5-11ea-8daf-3741e28b6270", line 18, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: highlight both lines `x = 5` and `print(x)`

Comment: This is expected behaviour. When you select single lines and execute them, the interpreter will have no knowledge of tue rest of your code. That should explain why you get an error — x has never been set.